# Shouldn't Carl's hat be too tight by now?

Tags: props, the-walking-dead

Carl has been wearing the same hat for 5 seasons of *The Walking Dead* now.  Given that he's been at the age where much of a person is continually growing, why does this hat still fit him?  Was it ever explained on the show that a new hat was found?

Comment: It's a magic hat. No, in all seriousness, Carl has definitely aged out of the hat. The actual actor that plays him is going to college now. http://www.soapoperaspy.com/2016/the-walking-dead-spoilers-shocking-clues-hint-carl-grimes-will-be-killed-off-on-twd-season-7/

Answer (score 13):

As much as I remember he was given the hat by his father. It was actually Rick's sheriff hat. So it already is an adult man's hat and I doubt Carl has already outgrown his father in terms of hat size.

Comment: Though the hair might fill it out a bit! :)

Comment: Bingo.  IIRC, they were in the barn on Hershel's farm in season 2 when Rick first gave the hat to Carl.  Carl has been wearing it ever since.

Answer (score 4):

Carl is using Rick's sheriff hat. When Rick sees him using it at first, he mentions they need to adjust it to his head, since the hat was not sized for Carl, and then takes off the sheriff badge. Now, I don't know about sheriff hats, but I've seen people using some filling around the edges to make a cowboy hat fit.

(This is speculation) I'm guessing they did something similar to his hat. As Carl grows, they just removed the filling.